# MongoDB batch operation best practices

Tags: mongodb

We're running a web application that serves around 700K RPM at peak times, which each one usually updating 2 documents in our database.

Our product's constraint is to update these documents immediatley (no lazy data dump), and we were wondering if it's more effective to use batch operations to do 2 updates, or just 2 separate update calls?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A batch will save you one round trip for a second update. It might not make a big difference, but it's worth trying.